# How to create a step definition to handle dynamic data entry?

Tags: java, webdriver, cucumber, cucumber-jvm, gherkin

I've searched a bit for this but can't find an exact example.  I have a form to fill in as a step.  The form fields look something like this:

Date:
Currency:
Total:
Description:

But not all of the fields are required to have data entered by the user.  Instead of writing several methods to account for the different combinations, like so:

```
(When I enter the 'Date' and 'Currency' and 'Total' and 'Description')  
(When I enter the 'Date' and 'Total')  
(When I enter the 'Currency' and 'Description')  
etc...
```

I'd like to somehow implement something like this, instead, in the feature file:

```
When I enter the following details:  
  |Date        |x    |       
  |Currency    |USD  |  
  |Total       |100  |   
  |Description |Test |
```

And then have a single method to handle any combination of data the user enters in that second column.

I've found sites that have this data table-driven example:

```
When I enter the following details:  
  |Date        |<date>        |       
  |Currency    |<currency>    |  
  |Total       |<total>       |   
  |Description |<description> |  

Example data:
  |date |currency |total |description |  
  |x    |USD      |100   |foo         |
  |y    |EUR      |200   |test        |
  |z    |HKD      |124   |bar         |
```

But that's not what I am after.  I don't need to iterate through a list of predetermined example data.  I hope I've summarized the problem clearly enough and someone knows a good place to go find an example of this kind of implementation.  Thanks for any advice!

Comment: It might just be me but your goal doesn't seem very clear to me.. You want to try different inputs as tests but you don't want to use the data table? Why? That's precisely what it's there to do. Could you expand a little bit more on why you want to avoid this approach?

Comment: I don't need to iterate over values for a single test.  Isn't that what the data table does?  Downstream, our application takes on different functionalities and UI paths based upon what the user entered in the fields.  In some of those scenarios, they won't fill in all of the fields.  This step is just a 'feeder' into subsequent steps based on what the user entered.  Sorry if that's not clear...it's hard to explain what I am trying to do without drawing it out.

Comment: even if that is the case, you can use the `Scenario Outline` as mentioned in the below answer which also constructs a table. But using that, you can also list the possible outcomes that a `When` step can produce as a test variable. If I understand correctly you want to test a set of inputs and corresponding outputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use a data table as an argument to a single non-repeated step. The first row of the data table must be a header:

```
When I enter the following details:
  |Name        |Value|
  |Date        |x    |
  |Currency    |USD  |
  |Total       |100  |
  |Description |Test |
```

Here's one possible way to use it in a step:

```
@Given("^I enter the following details:$")
public void i_enter_the_following_details(Map<String, String> details) throws Throwable {
    for Map.Entry<String, String> entry : details.entrySet() {
        String key = entry.getKey();
        String value = entry.getValue();
        switch (key) {
            case "Date":
                // add the date to the form
                break;
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

You can also get the table as a `DataTable`, a `List` of value objects, a `List<List<String>>` or a `List<Map<String>>` by declaring the parameter with that type. `Map<String, String>` seems easiest here.

I wrote the example this way because I'm assuming that you need to write different code to put each value in its field. If the code is the same for every field you might be able to just put the field's CSS selector in the data table and get rid of the switch.

More examples are [here](http://www.thinkcode.se/blog/2014/06/30/cucumber-data-tables) and [here](http://blog.czeczotka.com/2014/08/17/writing-cucumber-jvm-step-definitions/).

Comment: Just a quick question about this.  If a user does not happen to enter a date for example, does the date code still get executed?  The issue I am having is that I need the code to get executed only when the field's data is actually entered, and ignored if it's not.  I suppose I could maybe do this with some creative 'if/then' statements, but if I don't need to, that's even better.

Comment: Oh, I forgot to handle optional fields. Revised. Also note that there is a header row.

Comment: Ah, this might be exactly what i am after.  Thx, I will give this a shot and report back!

Comment: Confirmed.  This works perfectly.  Thanks, and thanks to all others who also replied with suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

What I could understand is you are trying to do combination testing of these 4 fields in the form. If that is so then you need to look at ScenaioOutline option which I think you are pointing to in what you call data table-driven. This will allow you to mention all your combinations as Example. Each example will be picked up and run as a separate scenario. You can modify your When to look like this -

```
Scenaio Outline:
...
...
When I enter the following details : Date <date> Currency <currency>.......
...
...
Examples:
  |date |currency |total |description |  
  |x    |USD      |100   |foo         |
  |y    |EUR      |200   |test        |
  |z    |HKD      |124   |bar         |
```

If you leave any of the data in the Examples table blank, blank will be send to the When step.

OR - If you want to get the data from the Whenstep in a list of objects which has instance variable corresponding to date, currency etc etc you can use the List parameter in your step definition. This saves you from writing pattern expressions. Then your step becomes

```
When I enter the following details : 
date   | currency   | .......
<date> | <currency> | .......
```

Make sure you have instance variables names match the table headings in the object that you create.